# Being able to pass in an argument to a function with no parameters

Tags: vb.net, function, parameters, compiler-errors

I'm using VB.NET currently and I've come across an issue. This is my class:

```
Public class foo

    Private _bar As Integer
    Private _name As String

    Public Sub New(bar As Integer)
        Me._bar = bar
        Me._name = getName(bar) '//Passing in an argument where it is not needed
    End Sub

    Private Function getName() As String

        '//Get name from database using _bar as a lookup(it's essentially a primary key)
        '//Name is obtained successfully (checked when debugging)
        '//Return name

    End Function

End Class
```

I am able to run this code despite passing in an argument to getName where it has no parameters. However, when I run it, the `Me._name` field always ends up with an empty string (not a null value as it initially starts out as) but I know that the `getName`method is returning the correct string as I checked it during debugging. If I remove the unneeded parameter then it works as expected and Me._name gets the returned value.

Why am I able to pass an argument where there shouldn't be one and not get any errors showing up in my error list? I tried this on a coworkers computer and they got a "Too many arguments" error.

Comment: looks weird.. I am also able to replicate this.. no error. Waiting for a gud explanation..

Comment: I thought it may have been to do with a shared(static) method with the same name I had in another class in a different project in the same solution. But after changing the name of the shared method the problem remained.

Comment: It is something like predefined overload function.. but still weird because return type is Char

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can call a function/sub with or without parentheses in VB.NET, so this

```
getName(bar)
```

is actually the same as this

```
getName()(bar)
```

and that's why there's no errors.

Furthermore, `getName(bar)` won't pass `bar` as a parameter to `getName` function, but it will return the `(bar+1)th` character of the value returned by `getName()`.

For example if we change `getName` function to this

```
Private Function getName() As String
    Return "test"
End Function
```

then `getName(1)` will be the same as `getName()(1)` and it will return the second character of `"test"`, which is `"e"`.

Comment: Wow, this is eye opening. I had no idea! Does this also happen in C# do you know?

Comment: This doesn't happen in C#. When you call a function in C# you have to add the parentheses in the end, so if your code above is in C# you will get an error and you won't be able to compile.

Answer (score 2):

`Chars` is default property of the `String` class.

```
Public NotInheritable Class [String]

    <__DynamicallyInvokable> _
    Public ReadOnly Default Property Chars(ByVal index As Integer) As Char
        <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable> _
        Get
    End Property

End Class
```

That is why you can call:

```
getName(bar)
```

Which is the equivalent to

```
getName.Chars(bar)
```

Now, if the `String` class didn't have any default property you would get an error saying `Expression is not an array or a method, and cannot have an argument list..`

```
Public Class foo

    Private _bar As Integer
    Private _name As [String]

    Public Sub New(bar As Integer)
        Me._bar = bar
        Me._name = getName(bar) '//Passing in an argument where it is not needed
    End Sub

    Private Function getName() As [String]
        '//Get name from database using _bar as a lookup(it's essentially a primary key)
        '//Name is obtained successfully (checked when debugging)
        '//Return name
    End Function

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class [String]

    Public ReadOnly Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```